# Keep a label position after text has been inputted

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a simple contact form to my site, using formspree. I've seen some styling online that looks great but i can't stop the label from returning back to its original position, thus going over what has been just inputted.

I've tried changing the transform values for the label-content class however it makes no difference, i'm not sure if some java-script would be a better solution than pure css.

```css
#contactform,
.form {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.field {
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.field:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.input {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 2rem;
}

textarea.input {
  resize: none;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.label {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  color: #0C6333;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.label::before,
.label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.label::before {
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.label::after {
  height: 2px;
  background: #0C6333;
  top: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.label-content {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

.input:focus,
.input--filled .input {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0s 0.3s;
}

.input:focus+.label::before,
.input--filled .label::before {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.input:focus+.label .label-content,
.input--filled .label .label-content {
  color: #cbc4c6;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 2.1em, 0) scale3d(0.65, 0.65, 1);
  transform: translate3d(0, 2.1em, 0) scale3d(0.65, 0.65, 1);
}

.button,
input[type=submit] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0C6333;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus,
.button:active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
}
```

```html
<form class="form" id="contactform" method="POST">
  <fieldset class="field">
    <input class="input" type="text" name="name" id="inputForm" required>
    <label class="label" for="name"><span name="label" class="label-content">Your name</span></label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="field">
    <input class="input" type="email" id="inputForm" name="_replyto" required>
    <label class="label" for="_replyto"><span class="label-content">Your email</span></label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="field">
    <textarea class="input" name="message" id="inputForm" rows="1" required></textarea>
    <label class="label" for="message"><span class="label-content">Your message</span></label>
  </fieldset>
  <input class="hidden" type="text" name="_gotcha" style="display:none">
  <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="_subject" value="Message via contact form">
  <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="" />

  <fieldset class="field">

    <input class="button submit" type="submit" value="Send">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Add js to keep an element in a certain state

Comment: agreeing with @SuperDJ - I would probably use JS to keep it there

Comment: What would you recommend i target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem to your solution can be done with a bit of Javascript since CSS doesn't support a state of the input i.e empty or filled.

You can add an empty `value` attribute to your `input` and `textarea` and add on a `onkeyup` listener to fill the `value` attribute with the user's input. So an input field will look like the following:

```
<input class="input"
       type="text"
       name="name"
       id="inputForm"
       onkeyup="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);"
       value="" required>
```

Now you can selected the "non-empty" input style them however you like, you can check the CSS below for an example

```
input:not([value=""]):not(:focus) + label .label-content,
textarea:not([value=""]):not(:focus) + label .label-content {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

You can find a working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f4r9v7bs/2/) and I'll be happy to answer any other questions you have.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a simple solution for you.

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('input');

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
  inputs[i].onchange = function(){ 
    (this.value) ? this.className = 'input filled' : this.className = 'input';
  }  
}
```

```css
#contactform,
.form {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.field {
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.field:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.input {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 2rem;
}

textarea.input {
  resize: none;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.label {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  color: #0C6333;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.label::before,
.label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.label::before {
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.label::after {
  height: 2px;
  background: #0C6333;
  top: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.label-content {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

.input:focus,
.input--filled .input {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0s 0.3s;
}

.input:focus+.label::before,
.input.filled+.label::before {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.input:focus+.label .label-content,
.input.filled+.label .label-content {
  color: #cbc4c6;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 2.1em, 0) scale3d(0.65, 0.65, 1);
  transform: translate3d(0, 2.1em, 0) scale3d(0.65, 0.65, 1);
}

.button,
input[type=submit] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0C6333;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus,
.button:active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
}
```

```html
<form class="form" id="contactform" method="POST">
  <fieldset class="field">
    <input class="input" type="text" name="name" id="inputFormName" required>
    <label class="label" for="name" id="name"><span name="label" class="label-content">Your name</span></label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="field">
    <input class="input" type="email" id="inputFormEmail" name="_replyto" required>
    <label class="label" for="_replyto" id="_replyto"><span class="label-content">Your email</span></label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="field">
    <textarea class="input" name="message" id="inputFormMessage" rows="1" required></textarea>
    <label class="label" for="message" id="message"><span class="label-content">Your message</span></label>
  </fieldset>
  <input class="hidden" type="text" name="_gotcha" style="display:none">
  <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="_subject" value="Message via contact form">
  <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="" />

  <fieldset class="field">

    <input class="button submit" type="submit" value="Send">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very close with this solution: [CodePen Here!](https://codepen.io/CodeBoyCode/pen/LJwBwo?editors=1100)

What I did was add the transformation settings into an `input:valid` element:

```
input:valid + .label .label-content, .input--filled .label .label-content {
color: #cbc4c6;

-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 2.1em, 0) scale3d(0.65, 0.65, 1);
transform: translate3d(0, 2.1em, 0) scale3d(0.65, 0.65, 1);
```

}

this does what is required, but ONLY if the information added is correct e.g. the email input looks like: example@example.com, I also couldn't get the textarea to work, it might be worth using `<input type="text">` instead of `<textarea>`

I'll keep working on it, but to be honest the JavaScript solutions will work best